# Interpolate in a 2x2x5 array to get new 2x2x9 array

Tags: matlab

How to interpolate in the 3rd dimension of a 2x2x5 array, based on 5 samples, to get a new 2x2x9 array, using a vector with 9 query values?

Possibly using griddedInterpolant or interp1, such as RT = interp1(X, R, XQ).

```
X = [1 3 5 7 9];
XQ = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
R =        [1  6; 11 16];
R(:,:,2) = [2  7; 12 17];
R(:,:,3) = [3  8; 13 18];
R(:,:,4) = [4  9; 14 19];
R(:,:,5) = [5 10; 15 20];
RT =        [1   6;   11   16  ];
RT(:,:,2) = [1.5 6.5; 11.5 16.5];
RT(:,:,3) = [2   7;   12   17  ];
RT(:,:,4) = [2.5 7.5; 12.5 17.5];
RT(:,:,5) = [3   8;   13   18  ];
RT(:,:,6) = [3.5 8.5; 13.5 18.5];
RT(:,:,7) = [4   9;   14   19  ];
RT(:,:,8) = [4.5 9.5; 14.5 19.5];
RT(:,:,9) = [5  10;   15   20  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/220471-how-to-interpolate-3d-data-based-on-changes-in-3rd-dimension):

```
A = zeros(2, 2, 9);
for i = 1:2
    for j = 1:2
        A(i, j, :) = interp1(X, squeeze(R(i, j, :)), XQ);
    end
end
```

I could't find a more elegant solution (without a loop).

In case you just need simple interpolation you may use [imresize3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize3.html):

```
B = imresize3(R, [2, 2, 9], 'linear');
```